# Help with catkin_make on an ARM

Tags: robotic-arm, catkin-make, catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to install ROS packages from source on Gumstix Overo. And I created the catkin work space following [this tutorial](http://ros.org/wiki/catkin/Tutorials/create_a_workspace). Everything works.

Then I used git to download [bondcore package](https://github.com/ros/bond_core) to /catkin_ws/src directory.

Then I run "catkin_make" in /catkin_ws. This is output:

```
root@linaro-alip:~/catkin_ws# catkin_make 
lBase path: /root/catkin_ws
Source space: /root/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /root/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /root/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /root/catkin_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "make -j1" in "/root/catkin_ws/build"
####
```

It seems catkin cannot find bondcore to build.

Then I try to build bondcore without catkin_make following [this tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/catkin/Tutorials/using_a_workspace). However, I got error while running "cmake ../src"

```
root@linaro-alip:~/catkin_ws/build# cmake ../src
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /root/catkin_ws/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /root/ros_core_ws/install
-- This workspace overlays: /root/ros_core_ws/install
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gtest': gtests will be built
-- catkin 0.5.52
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- ~~  traversing packages in topological order:
-- ~~  - beginner_tutorials
-- ~~  - bond
-- ~~  - bond_core
-- ~~  - smclib
-- ~~  - bondcpp
-- ~~  - bondpy
-- ~~  - test_bond
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- +++ add_subdirectory(beginner_tutorials)
-- +++ add_subdirectory(bond_core-master/bond)
CMake Error at /root/ros_core_ws/install/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:71 (find_package):
  Could not find a configuration file for package message_generation.

  Set message_generation_DIR to the directory containing a CMake
  configuration file for message_generation.  The file will have one of the
  following names:

    message_generationConfig.cmake
    message_generation-config.cmake

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  bond_core-master/bond/CMakeLists.txt:4 (find_package)


CMake Error at bond_core-master/bond/CMakeLists.txt:6 (add_message_files):
  Unknown CMake command "add_message_files".


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Anyone know why this happened? Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54539/help-with-catkin_make-on-an-arm/) by [AdrianPeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/3585/adrianpeng/) on ROS Answers with karma: 441 on 2013-02-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are asking to build the joy target, which doesn't exist. See:

```
####
#### Running command: "make -j1 joy" in "/root/catkin_ws/build"
####
make: *** No rule to make target `joy'.  Stop.
Invoking "make" failed
```

In stead of calling `catkin_make joy` simply call `catkin_make` and it will build everything in your workspace.  In a new version of `catkin_make` (0.6.53+) there will be a --pkg option where you can specify individual packages from the workspace that you wish to build. See:

https://github.com/ros/catkin/pull/352

---

Originally posted by [WilliamWoodall](https://answers.ros.org/users/3078/williamwoodall/) with karma: 1626 on 2013-02-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AdrianPeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/3585/adrianpeng/) on 2013-02-06**:
I tried both "catkin_make" and "catkin_make --pkg joy". Unfortunately, both of them didn't work. I updated the output.

**Comment by [WilliamWoodall](https://answers.ros.org/users/3078/williamwoodall/) on 2013-02-06**:
`catkin_make --pkg joy` won't work until the next release of catkin...  What is in your `/catkin/src` directory? It looks like there was nothing to build.

**Comment by [AdrianPeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/3585/adrianpeng/) on 2013-03-09**:
I download bondcore package from https://github.com/ros/bond_core to /catkin_ws/src. But catkin_make cannot find it. So I try to build bondcore without catkin_make, I got some errors which I updated in my question.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

have a look at [this tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/groovy/Installation/Linaro/Source)
There is also a SD card image with ROS preinstalled on that page

---

Originally posted by [kalectro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3904/kalectro/) with karma: 1554 on 2013-03-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AdrianPeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/3585/adrianpeng/) on 2013-03-09**:
Hi kalectro, in my SD card image with ROS preinstalled, everything works except catkin_make. Is there any other way to solve this issue? Thanks.

**Comment by [kalectro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3904/kalectro/) on 2013-03-09**:
Try catkin_make --force-cmake and make sure you have all package dependencies installed. Just downloading one package is usually not enough. Go to your src folder and do
wstool merge http://packages.ros.org/web/rosinstall/generate/raw/groovy/bond_core;
wstool update